# Target/style an element’s attributes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to change the style of the div element below using JavaScript, but by using its attribute as the selector instead of the class:

```
<div class="radio-wrapper" data-option-method="Option-A">
```

For example, I'm able to achieve the desired effect with the following CSS:

```
.radio-wrapper[data-option-method="Option-A"] { display: none; }
```

But I'm not having any luck when I attempt the same in the JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".radio-wrapper[data-option-method="Option-A"]").style.display = "none";
```

I'm sure this is a fairly simple one, but I'm struggling to research a clear answer, greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: use single quote `document.getElementsByClassName(".radio-wrapper[data-option-method='Option-A']").style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a clear syntax error.  Your browser console is undoubtedly pointing this out to you.  Always check the console for errors.

Since your string contains double-quotes, use single-quotes for the string itself:

```
'.radio-wrapper[data-option-method="Option-A"]'
```

Aside from that, `document.getElementsByClassName` is the wrong function to use here.  What you have isn't a class name, it's a more complex selector.  `document.querySelector` can find the element based on that:

```
document.querySelector('.radio-wrapper[data-option-method="Option-A"]').style.display = "none";
```

Alternatively, if there are *multiple* matching elements and you want to target all of them, use `querySelectorAll` and iterate over the results:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-wrapper[data-option-method="Option-A"]');
for (let el of elements) {
  el.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that isn't the class name. ([data-option-method="Option-A"] is an attribute)
Try it with:

```js
document.querySelector('.radio-wrapper[data-option-method="Option-A"]')
```

If you want to select multiple, use querySelectorAll but bare in mind that returns an array.

Also watch out for the `, ", and ' in strings, either escape them with a " or combine them as I did.